# Время до завершения операции

Tags: c#

Как рассчитать время завершения операции. Пока я в цикле с помощь StopWatch замеряю прошедшее время и рассчитываю среднюю скорость одной итерации. Далее оставшееся количество итерация на скорость...  Что-то результаты получаются не ОК.

Comment: Приведите лучше код, а лучше его упрощённый вариант. "В цикле" и "скорость одной итерации" вместе выглядят подозрительно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас есть **N** операций, которые выполняется в цикле.

мы знаем что с 1-ой операции до **X**-ой операции прошло 10 минут,

значит у нас скорость **V** = X операций в 10 минут = X / 10 * 60 операций в секунду

т.е. N-X операций будет выполняться (N-X)*V секунд, собственно ответ )

**P.S.** если с помощью watch ходишь по циклу, то в реальное действие операции добавляется время твоего просмотра, соответственно скорость меняется...

Comment: "значит у нас скорость V = X операций в 10 минут = X * 10 * 60 операций в секунду"
Логика мне подсказывает, что скорость вычисляется как V = X/10*60 или я не прав?

Comment: ой, вы правы )

Answer (score 1):

Windows не является операционной системой реального времени. Ей ничто не мешает в следующий момент остановить поток выполнения твоего функционала на неопределенный период времени. Так что отображай процент выполненной работы.

Comment: Мне особая точность не важна. Я делаю экспорт из одной БД в другую. Так что вряд ли погрешность даже в секундах (минутах) ухудшит мой результат.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, что ты берешь первую итерацию цикла и принимаешь её за среднее время обработки одной итерации. Такое могло бы проканать в однозадачных ОС. Тут тебе надо вычислять среднее время цикла при каждой итерации. 
Запости кусок кода, будет проще разобраться.
Можно попробовать вычислить это при помощи теории вычислительной сложности: http://habrahabr.ru/post/104219/

Comment: Замечательный пример bullshit'a. Допустим, у вас есть функция, реализующая некоторый алгоритм, для которой строго доказана ее алгоритмическая сложность ‛O(N)‛ при равномерном весовом критерии. Вычислите, пожалуйста, сколько времени потребуется, чтобы запустить эту функцию 300 раз для наборов данных известной размерности.

Comment: Нет, я считаю среднее время выполнение одной итерации. Вроде бы я получил приемлемый результат. Возможно была ошибка округления при делении. Я уже перепробовал миллион вариантов.